# Is income from bank account bonuses taxable on my state tax return?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax

I'm a student in the US on an F-1 visa. Last year (2017), I opened ten new bank accounts, all of which had promotional offers. As a result, I received around $3000, and this has been reported on Form 1099-INTs issued by the ten banks. I know this $3000 is considered to be interest income. When I file Form 1099NR-EZ using a software, it does not include this as taxable income at all. I searched on the internet, and the reason seems to be that interest income is not taxable for nonresident aliens.

My question is this. Do I need to declare and /or pay taxes on this income for my state tax return? Am I even considered a resident of any state? My state is PA. Thanks for the help. I should also mention that not all these banks are in Pennsylvania, so it may further complicate matters.

Comment: Seriously ? Why did you limit yourself to just ten?

Comment: Why do you think you're eligible to file 1040NR-EZ? The instructions for that form state: "Note. If you had taxable interest or dividend income, you must use Form 1040NR."